# Bootstrap modal causes page to shift right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a little problem with Bootstrap modal on my website. I would like the page behind the modal to be fixed which is why I have added the following code:

```
  .modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

However this causes the page to shift to the right (at least in Firefox) when the modal is open and shift back again when it closes.

Any one who has a solution to this?

Comment: how are we supposed to know what you're talking about. please post the relevant markup. a working demo would be most helpful.

Comment: are you losing the scroll bar?

Comment: Presumably you aren't using Bootstrap v3.3.0 (i.e. latest).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you use transform to force the modal to center and then make sure position fixed as well. http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/